# Update-Database error: The certification chain was issued by an untrusted entity. (True Solution?)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssl-certificate, entity-framework-migrations

I was trying to Update-Database after doing a migration of my project. Then this error appeared:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certification chain was issued by an untrusted entity.)

I finally resolved it by adding `TrustServerCertificate=True` in my connection string. Then I researched a bit and found out that this solution is unsecure since it can lead to man in the middle attacks. My question is, how can I solve this error so that it can be applied to all production environments?

Comment: Use a certificate issued by a trusted root?

Comment: SQL Server instances are installed with self-signed certificates by default. There are tools available to capture the public key portion of an SQL Server's self-signed certificate which then allows you to add it to the Trusted Roots stores of connecting computers. Alternatively get your trusted Organisation CA to issue Server Authentication certificates whose CN (Common Name), DNS Name and/or SAN (Subject Alternate Name) properties contain the fully-qualified domain name of your instances and install them on the target instances via SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I think it's specifically the SAN that is the one that's supposed to be checked against the hostname.